# Create a slug for a page in WordPress

Tags: php, seo

How can I create a slug for a page in WordPress?  I see that there are custom formats available, but I would like to be able to specify things like:

```
mydomain.com/about

mydomain.com/home

mydomain.com/portfolio
```

etc.
Is there a plugin or technique that I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: that would be nice. I'm open to plugins.  I'll repost to Wordpress I can't get a hit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom permalink you will most likely want to use is /%postname%/

Which will get the structure that you show above. (mydomain.com/about, mydomain.com/home)

If you want to edit the slug, it's right underneath the title of the post ("Permalink"), click edit.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the slug is not visible on the edit-page screen (I think by default). Try going to 'screen-options' and enabling the tick box for slugs and you'll find it then at the end of the edit-page

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the slug at the top of the "edit page" page

Answer (score 0):

In order to use custom slugs in WordPress you need to use permalinks.

Permalink structure can be custom and you can read about it here:

- [using permalinks (at WordPress)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Once you have created permalinks you can go to the page editing screen and click edit next to the page url under the page title
to edit and change the current automatic slug given by WordPress.

The automatic slug given by WordPress is your page title as was 
saved (automatically) in the first draft.